# angular - How to show dynamic loading message for each lazy modules on <app-root>

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

I have two lazy modules in my project. I want to show two different loading messages on .

The content which is inside the app-root element in the index.hmtl, it comes same for two lazy loading modules before it renders.

Ex, `<app-root>Loading</app-root>`

Is it possible to show dynamic "Loading" messages for lazy loading modules in angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the Loading text from there. Example:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

Hope this works.